# ruby/cucumber: unable to run "bundle install"

Tags: cucumber, bundle-install

I've got a ruby/cucumber project that I'm setting in a new windows machine. Everything seems to be in place (gemfile, rakefile, ruby 1.9.3 installed) but when I run 'bundle install' I get the message:

```
"jruby.exe" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable programme or batch file.
```

Any idea where the problem can be? I don't know why it's even throwing that jruby error...

I've got exactly the same setup in another machine that doesn't have jruby installed either but 'bundle install' works fine there... :S

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The machine I was using was in a mess of environment variables and corrupt past installations of both, ruby and jruby.

Uninstalling everything and starting from scratch fixed the problem.